# I2C LCD Serial Interface Board not displaying text

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, lcd

The code dont gives error, but not displays "Hello World"

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

// Set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

void setup() {
  // initialize the LCD
  lcd.begin();
  // Turn on the blacklight and print a message.
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.print("Hello, world!");
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the same display as that library is designed for?

Answer (score 3):

This can be due a lot of reasons, among:

Most common:

- Backlight is set too low (there should be a small dial)
- Circuit problem (recheck), and post it.
- The I2C address is wrong, there are sketches to check it.

Less common:

- Broken LCD
- Broken Arduino
- No power on Arduino (check LED)